# Ошибка requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='....ru', port=443):

Tags: python, requests, macos, ssl

Написал код для парсинга всех фото со страницы выбранной модели с одного сайта. На винде все работало без каких-либо проблем. Перешел на Mac. И теперь при запуске скрипта выдает ошибку:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='....ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /catalog/... (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)')))
```

Пробовал уже до фига всего, и verify=False, и certifi устанавливал, указывая .pem-файл в качестве сертификата в запросе, и с urlib3 шаманил, и прочее-прочее. Но ничего не помогает. Очень прошу помочь, так как скрипт используется в рабочих целях.

Код скрипта:

```
def download_photos(url, model):
    os.makedirs(folder := f'/Users/.../Desktop/Temp_photo/{model}')
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    domain = url.split('.')[0] + '.ru'
    if '...' in domain: data = ("gallery-list__item js-gallery-list__item", 'data-big')
    else: data = ("web-gallery__fancybox-thumb js-web-gallery__fancybox-thumb", 'href')

    count = 0
    for li in (soup.findAll(class_=data[0])):
        count += 1
        photo_file = domain + li.get(data[1])
        print(photo_file)
        wget.download(url=photo_file, out=folder + f'\\{model}_{count}.jpg')

url = 'https://....ru/catalog/...'
model = 'KFW 104'

download_photos(url, model)
```